# How could the storm bolt receive multiple type tuple from different spout or other bolt?

Tags: java, tuples, apache-storm

I have two serializable class A and B.And there are two kind of spout A_spout and B_spout.Each spout emit parallelism class to bolt C.But there's no difference about tuple in method execute,so how could I distinguish them?

Answer (score 1):

Each input `Tuple` in `Bolt.execute()` carries some meta data which also contains the input operator it originates from:

```java
public void execute(Tuple input) {
    if(input.getSourceComponent().equals("A_Spout")) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // data from B_Spout; do something different
    }
}
```